# PHP/Regex. Replacing ' ' with &nbsp; if within ()

Tags: php, regex

I cannot seem to find a regex to do the following.

I need to replace  (space) with `&nbsp;` but only if it is within brackets.

E.g.

```
hello test('test some more') ;
```

Needs to be

```
hello test('test&nbsp;some&nbsp;more') ;
```

Any help would be great :)

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction.

Comment: Hi Lanzz, what do you mean? The reason for doing this is very unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically that can be done with regex:

```
$str = "hello test('test some more again') dads dasds ('and some more');";

$str = preg_replace('#(?<=\()([^)]+?) | (?=[^()]*\))#', '$1&nbsp;', $str);
var_dump($str);
```

In other words, we replace here a whitespace that is either preceded by `(`, but not `(...)`, OR followed by `)`, but, again, not `(...)`.

The question is, though, whether you should take precautions against nested parenthesis.